# gem 'zip-codes' not fetching zip of france in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hello I am using `gem 'zip-codes'` to match the zip-code with given state and city its working fine for US country, state and city. But for *FRANCE* its not working it as in European countries we don't have states we have province so its not working for that. I have written given code in my model:

```
validate :zip_and_city_match, on: [:create, :update]

def zip_and_city_match
    @zip = ZipCodes.identify(self.zip)
    if @zip.present?
      unless self.state_code == @zip[:state_code] && self.city == @zip[:city]
        self.errors.add(:zip, 'Does not match the provided city and state')
      end
    else
      self.errors.add(:zip, 'Invalid Zip')
    end
end
```

If I give country = France, state_code= Île-de-France, city = Paris and zip = 75001 so it gives error ***Does not match the provided city and state***. I had also tried `http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/08/21/zipcode-validation-using-geokit-in-rails/` this but this also don't work for me. Please help me out how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems this gem support only US based zip code from what i can see on their github account: https://github.com/monterail/zip-codes/blob/master/lib/data/US.yml

Comment: I had also tried http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/08/21/zipcode-validation-using-geokit-in-rails/ this but this also don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

this `gem 'zip-codes'` only supports US zipcode. So i think you should go for other solution. See this file of `gem 'zip-codes'` [US.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monterail/zip-codes/master/lib/data/US.yml).For more information, you can go through the file of this gem [zip-codes](https://github.com/monterail/zip-codes)